# IOS SMS Sending using UI Shared Application

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I cannot pass phone number to SMS.

```
NSString *myString = lblMobilePhone.text;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sms://%@",myString]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MFMessageComposeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) is how you should be doing it.

If you want to do it your way you need to change it to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sms:%@",myString]` (removed the two // from the url)

Comment: I removed // and test but still it is not not working and cannot display SMS service.is there any other way to pass the phono number.thanks for ur help.